# Windows Phone Application settings

Tags: windows-phone-7, appsettings

It seems Application Settings on Windows Phone are not secure and encrypted. I used isolated storage tool to pull all app files and folder fro mthe device and AppSettings file seems to be plain XML.

What about app linq databases? .sdf file seems to be encrypted.

I need to store very sensitive data that needs to be accessed both from the app and from background agent which is running in a separate process. They both seem to access application settings but since the storage is not secure I really cannot use app settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ProtectedData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28VS.95%29.aspx) class to encrypt your sensitive data, then store it in the application settings or directly in the isolated storage.

For instance:

```cs
// Encrypting
var encryptedData = ProtectedData.Protect(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world!"), null);

// Decrypting
var sensitiveData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ProtectedData.UnProtect(encryptedData, null));
```